# Upload image from android to django rest framework using google app engine + google cloud sql + cloudinary.

Tags: android, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, cloudinary

i have a regist form with their fields, but I can not upload an image from android to cloudinary, and save the url in google cloud sql.
my android code:

```
            String senderPart = MyApplication.getInstance().getPrefManager().getUser().getUrl();

            entity.addPart("perfil", new FileBody(sourceFile));

            entity.addPart("user", new StringBody(senderPart));
```

senderPart is the url from my user.
sourceFile is the path of my image profile.

django rest framework code model:

```
class AgregarFotoPerfil(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    perfil = CloudinaryField('perfil')
```

view.py:

```
class PerfilViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = AgregarFotoPerfil.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ImgPerfilSerializer
```

serializer.py:

```
class ImgPerfilSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = AgregarFotoPerfil
    fields = ('url', 'perfil', 'user')
```

google app engine error:

```
TypeError: Got a `TypeError` when calling `AgregarFotoPerfil.objects.create()`. This may be because you have a writable field on the serializer class that is not a valid argument to `AgregarFotoPerfil.objects.create()`. You may need to make the field read-only, or override the ImgPerfilSerializer.create() method to handle this correctly.
```

Original exception text was:  has type , but expected one of: str, unicode.

Comment: Why don't you use google cloud storage instead of cloudinary?

Comment: Hi, did you thought in google blob store and cloud storage? They services designed for your requirement. Take a look [Here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/media-upload#implementation)

Comment: Google storage is a container file, cloudinary offers a complete image management.

Comment: Any updates? Can you specify where exactly does it fail? Is the image being properly uploaded to the Cloudinary account?